# $_POST array in wrong order?

Tags: html, arrays, post, submit

like to submit the array via $_POST, it works only with one foreach, how can i combine two foreach-arrays without getting everything doubled?

i tried it with "keTitle" and and "keSoll", but only once at a time works..

html:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <td>Kühlgerät</td>
        <td>Soll</td>
        <td>Ist</td>                
    </thead>
    <tbody> 

<?php

$todo_query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM temp_ke WHERE ListID = '1'");

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_object($todo_query))
{
?>  
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">
                <?php echo "$row2->keTitle"; ?>
                <input name="Title[<? echo "$row2->keTitle";?>]" value="<? echo "$row2->keTitle";?>" type="hidden">
            </th>                               
            <td><?php echo "$row2->keSoll"; ?> °C<br>
                <input name="SollWert[<? echo "$row2->keSoll";?>]" value="<? echo "$row2->keSoll";?>" type="hidden">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="shortinput" name="IstWert[]" value="" type="text"> °C<br>
            </td>                                       
        </tr>
<?php }} ?>         
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="tablefooter">Ausgefüllt von: <input name="Mitarbeiter" value="" type="text"></div>
<br>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Temperaturen eintragen">

</form>     
</div>
```

---

next page to $_POST to:

```
<?php

    foreach ($_POST['Title'] as $keTitle) {
        foreach ($_POST['SollWert'] as $keSoll) {
            echo "$keSoll<br>";
            echo "$keTitle<br><br>";    
        }
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

form value

```
$_POST['Title'] = 'Mein Titel';
$_POST['SollWert'] = '123';
```

**thats the array:**

```
$ksTitle = $_POST['Title'];
$keSoll = $_POST['SollWert'];

echo "$keSoll<br/>";
echo "$keTitle<br/>";
```

**or in foreach:**

```
foreach( $_POST AS $value){
  echo $value . "<br/>";
}
```

output:

> Mein Titel
>
> 123

Comment: with this i will get the Title, but how to get the "keSoll" at the same time?  foreach($_POST['Title'] AS $value){
  echo $value . "<br/>";
}

Comment: The best solution is the first code ( `echo $_POST['Title']; echo $_POST['SollWert']; ` ) without a foreach. 
Sample: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2c7b9f37800145fef5702b6b0ff111681d7c734d

Comment: but thats not an array, isn't it?

Comment: <input name="Title[]"> This in the input-field?